# Misunderstanding the calculation of the potential for a system of 2 concentric shells

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

Let's say we have 2 concentric shells. The little one has a charge $Q_1$ and a radius $R_1$ and the greater one has a charge $Q_2$ and a radius $R_2$ with $R_2$ > $R_1$.

We want to calculate the potentials so :

1) $r > R_2 :$

$V(r) = \frac{(Q_1 + Q_2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}$

$V(R_2) = \frac{(Q_1 + Q_2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{R_2}$

2) $R_1 < r < R_2 :$

This is where I don't understand. I would say that it's the difference of potential $V(R_2) - V(R_1)$

I would calculate : $V(r) = \frac{(Q_1 + Q_2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{R_2} - \frac{(Q_1)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{R_1}$

However we have : $\frac{(Q_1)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r} + \frac{(Q_2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{R_2}$

3) $r < R_1 :$

$V(r) = 0$ (no charges inside)

I suppose that the following potential comes from the fact that to bring a charge from $+\infty$ we have to "fight against" the contributions of the charge $Q_2$ uniformly distributed on the sphere of radius $R_2$ and of the charge $Q_1$ uniformly distributed on the sphere of radius $R_1$ ?

$V(R_1) = \frac{(Q_1)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{(Q_2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{R_2}$

But why don't we have (following the logic of the case $r > R_2$) : $V(R_1) = \frac{(Q_1)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{(Q_1 + Q_2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{R_2}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 3) $r < R_1 :$  $V(r) = 0$ (no charges inside)

Is an incorrect statement.
Inside the inner shell the **electric field** is zero and the **potential** is constant.
It can be zero if you define it to be so, however, from what you have written for case **1** you have taken the zero of potential to be at infinity.

The electric field outside the outer shell is due to charge $Q_1+Q_2$, that between the two shells is due to charge $Q_1$.

The potential outside of the outer shell is $V(r) = \dfrac{(Q_1 + Q_2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\dfrac{1}{r}$ and so at the outer shell it is $V(R_2) = \dfrac{(Q_1 + Q_2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\dfrac{1}{R_2}$

The potential of the inner shell relative to the outer shell is is $ \dfrac{Q_1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left (\dfrac{1}{R_1}-\dfrac{1}{R_2}\right )$

So the potential of the inner shell is $V(R_1) = \dfrac{(Q_1 + Q_2)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\dfrac{1}{R_2}+\dfrac{Q_1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left (\dfrac{1}{R_1}-\dfrac{1}{R_2}\right ) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left (\dfrac{Q_1}{R_1}+\dfrac{Q_2}{R_2}\right )$

If the charges are positive the potentials look something like this.

[image]